# rclone OneDrive: "Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax"

Tags: onedrive, freebsd

I'm just trying to use both rclone and OneDrive for the first time, in conjunction. On a Windows PC, I ran `rsync config` and it produced a configuration file. I can then `rclone sync . OneDrive:test` and within a few seconds the folder `test` appears in the OneDrive interface. I ultimately want to use this on a FreeBSD machine. I copied the entire config file verbatim from the Windows machine to the FreeBSD machine (it contains only one section describing the parameters for the `OneDrive` remote), but when I run the same test command `rclone sync . OneDrive:test`, I get the following output:

```
rclone@GALLERY:~ % rclone sync . OneDrive:test
2019/01/28 14:24:59 Failed to create file system for "OneDrive:test": failed to get root: unauthenticated: Must be authenticated to use '/drive' syntax
rclone@GALLERY:~ %
```

I'm not sure what to try next. The configuration is literally identical to the Windows machine where it works just fine. Eliding the personal bits, this is the contents of the config file:

```
[OneDrive]
type = onedrive
drive_type = business
token = {"access_token":"eyJ0eXAfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxAVeiklCYIgAA","expiry":"2019-01-28T15:11:32.2443131-06:00"}
drive_id = b!KW9cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxvBSZB
```

What am I doing wrong?

*And one other question as an aside -- what happens when that token expires? <s>I don't see any refresh token, and the expiry is just 1 hour from the token creation.</s> In my fervour to take out the actual token, I didn't notice that the selection I replaced with 'x's contained the end of the token and the start of a refresh token. So I guess I should re-ask this aside as, is rsync going to automatically refresh the token and rewrite the config file each time it expires? So, as long as I don't let the refresh token expire and don't have exceptionally bad luck with lost packets, I should get an unbroken chain of refreshes?*

> I have answered the aside. On the Windows machine where it's working, verbose debug output explicitly said the token had expired and it was rewriting the config file with a new token. So, that's that question!

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problem. FreeBSD's package system has rclone version 1.43. The version on Windows where I observed it working was version 1.45. This doesn't seem like that big of a difference, but it would appear that 1.45 works and 1.43 doesn't work. I uninstalled the FreeBSD 1.43 package and instead used the 1.45 distribution offered by the rclone web site, and with no other changes, it now works. Go figure!